# Convert a data frame with one polygon per row to an `sf` object

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a data frame representing one quadrilateral on the earth's surface per row, structured like this:

```
d = data.frame(
    lon.c1 = c(-65.64025, -79.11267, -84.44683, -76.35987, -77.18833),
    lat.c1 = c(18.35419, 35.90454, 33.70796, 36.97808, 37.27661),
    lon.c2 = c(-65.60549, -79.0479, -84.31132, -76.3124, -77.13755),
    lat.c2 = c(18.36057, 35.92863, 33.77171, 36.99247, 37.29281),
    lon.c3 = c(-65.62023, -79.07303, -84.33958, -76.33563, -77.16152),
    lat.c3 = c(18.42399, 35.99039, 33.83202, 37.05477, 37.35499),
    lon.c4 = c(-65.65499, -79.13784, -84.47516, -76.38314, -77.21233),
    lat.c4 = c(18.41762, 35.96629, 33.76823, 37.04037, 37.33878))
```

I want to get the area of each quadrilateral, in square meters. It sounds like recent versions of `sf` support real spherical area calculations with `st_area`, but I'd first need to convert this data into an `sf` feature collection with one polygon per row. How do I do that? I could fumble my way through by looping over the rows, building a polygon out of each, and then putting all the polygons into a feature collection, but is there a slicker (and perhaps vectorized) way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `summarise` + `st_cast` to create polygon from groups of points. First, pivot to long and repeat the first point in the end to close the polygon:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

d_pol <- data.frame(d, lon.c5 = d[[1]], lat.c5 = d[[2]])
d_long <- pivot_longer(d_pol, everything(), 
                       names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)", names_to = c(".value", "c"))

d_long %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat")) %>% 
  group_by(p = cumsum(c == "c1")) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON")
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
st_as_sf(crs = 4326L, `[`(
    melt(
        as.data.table(d)[, c(.SD, list(
            lon.c5 = lon.c1,
            lat.c5 = lat.c1,
            polygon = .I))],
        measure = patterns("lon", "lat")),
    by = "polygon",
    j = .(g = list(st_polygon(list(cbind(value1, value2)))))))
```

---

Another possibility is to use `st_polygon`:

`sf` requires a specific format to convert a vector to a polygon. It has to be a matrix with two columns (long, lat), nested in a list, and the last row has to be identical to the first row. E.g.:

```r
list(rbind(c(-1,-1), c(1,-1), c(1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,-1)))
```

AFAIK, `st_polygon` is not vectorized, so you need to use a for loop there. You could also create a multipolygon and then divide into polygons.
Here's how you can do it:

```r
d_long <- pivot_longer(d_pol, everything(), names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)", names_to = c(".value", "c"))
spl <- split(d_long[-1], cumsum(d_long$c == "c1"))
st_as_sfc(lapply(spl, \(x) st_polygon(list(as.matrix(x)))))
```

---

output

```r
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -84.47516 ymin: 18.35419 xmax: -65.60549 ymax: 37.35499
CRS:           NA
# A tibble: 5 × 2
      p                                                                   geometry
  <int>                                                                  <POLYGON>
1     1 ((-65.65499 18.41762, -65.64025 18.35419, -65.62023 18.42399, -65.60549 1…
2     2 ((-79.13784 35.96629, -79.11267 35.90454, -79.07303 35.99039, -79.0479 35…
3     3 ((-84.47516 33.76823, -84.44683 33.70796, -84.33958 33.83202, -84.31132 3…
4     4 ((-76.38314 37.04037, -76.35987 36.97808, -76.33563 37.05477, -76.3124 36…
5     5 ((-77.21233 37.33878, -77.18833 37.27661, -77.16152 37.35499, -77.13755 3…
```

Comment: after your `melt()` call you can pipe it into `sfheaders` to build the polygons directly `melt()[order(polygon)] |> sfheaders::sf_polygon(x = "value2", y = "value1", polygon_id = "polygon")`, as `sfheaders` _is_ vectorised

Answer (score 3):

another approach, given your example data d:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyr)

d |>
mutate(ID = paste0('poly_', row_number()), .before = 1) |>
rowwise() |>
mutate(
  poly = list(cbind(c_across(starts_with('lon')),
                    c_across(starts_with('lat'))
                    ) %>%
              rbind(., .[1,]) |> ## see (1)
              st_multipoint() |> 
              st_cast('POLYGON')
              )
) |>
select(ID, poly) |>
st_sf()
```

```
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -84.47516 ymin: 18.35419 xmax: -65.60549 ymax: 37.35499
CRS:           NA
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  ID                                                                        poly
  <chr>                                                                <POLYGON>
1 poly_1 ((-65.64025 18.35419, -65.60549 18.36057, -65.62023 18.42399, -65.6549~
2 poly_2 ((-79.11267 35.90454, -79.0479 35.92863, -79.07303 35.99039, -79.13784~
3 poly_3 ((-84.44683 33.70796, -84.31132 33.77171, -84.33958 33.83202, -84.4751~
4 poly_4 ((-76.35987 36.97808, -76.3124 36.99247, -76.33563 37.05477, -76.38314~
5 poly_5 ((-77.18833 37.27661, -77.13755 37.29281, -77.16152 37.35499, -77.2123~
```

(1) append initial row of lon/lat to the end of the lon/lat matrix to close the polygon